# How do I raise an exception in Rails so it behaves like other Rails exceptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I would like to raise an exception so that it does the same thing a normal Rails exception does. Specially, show the exception and stack trace in development mode and show "We're sorry, but something went wrong" page in production mode.

I tried the following:

```
raise "safety_care group missing!" if group.nil?
```

But it simply writes `"ERROR signing up, group missing!"` to the development.log file

Comment: the error message you posted does not seem to come from this exception (it's a different message) is this really what you're seeing?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special, it should just be working.

When I have a fresh rails app with this controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    raise "error"
  end
end
```

and go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/foo/`

I am seeing the exception with a stack trace.

You might not see the whole stacktrace in the console log because Rails (since 2.3) [filters lines from the stack trace that come from the framework itself.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#quieter-backtraces)

See `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb` in your Rails project

Comment: Excellent, concise answer.

Comment: The skitch link (seeing the exception with a stack trace) isn't working anymore

Comment: @levinalex will this be safe in production mode to show the stacktrace?

Comment: @levinalex - thank you alex.  is there any way of adding a custom string to the error message ?

Answer (score 69):

You can do it like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ## Exception Handling
  class NotActivated < StandardError
  end

  rescue_from NotActivated, :with => :not_activated

  def not_activated(exception)
    flash[:notice] = "This user is not activated."
    Event.new_event "Exception: #{exception.message}", current_user, request.remote_ip
    redirect_to "/"
  end

  def show
      // Do something that fails..
      raise NotActivated unless @user.is_activated?
  end
end
```

What you're doing here is creating a class "NotActivated" that will serve as Exception. Using raise, you can throw "NotActivated" as an Exception. rescue_from is the way of catching an Exception with a specified method (not_activated in this case). Quite a long example, but it should show you how it works.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: This does not show the exception and stack trace in development mode and show "We're sorry, but something went wrong" page in production mode.

Comment: The "we're sorry" page is actually your web server's 500 error handler. Check your .htaccess file and you will usually see it there

Comment: Maybe not an answer to the OP but a very useful example, thank you!

Answer (score 22):

If you need an easier way to do it, and don't want much fuss, a simple execution could be:

```
raise Exception.new('something bad happened!')
```

This will raise an exception, say `e` with `e.message = something bad happened!`

and then you can rescue it as you are rescuing all other exceptions in general.

Comment: It is not a good idea to raise or rescue 'Exception' itself, try to use StandardError instead. See this for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby